# showing ETA in 12 hours format react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, time, expo

does any one know this could be achieved in react native, I am working on an location based app that requires showing ETA to the customer. However, I do not want to show just 25mins away, I would like to implement 'arriving 'Arriving Today, 9:45 AM. which implies the current time is 9:20 and the ETA is added to the current time.
something like the image below

[image]

Comment: The question isn't really specific enough.

Comment: If you want to add 25 minutes to the current time, and display the current time, the package moment.js makes it easy to work with and display date times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it using the below function:

```
  getETA(minutesLeftInArrival) {
    let arrivalTimeLeft = minutesLeftInArrival * 60 * 1000; // convert to unix timestamp
    let currentTime = Date.now(); //TIME RIGHT NOW
    let timeToArrive = currentTime + arrivalTimeLeft; // TIME OF ARRIVAL
    let time = new Date(timeToArrive).toTimeString(); // TIME in 24 hour format
    time = time.split(" ")[0];  // Remove GMT+...... from time
    time = time.replace(/:\d\d([ ap]|$)/,'$1'); // remove seconds from time
    let H = +time.substr(0, 2);
    let hour = H % 12 || 12; 
    let ampm = (H < 12 || H === 24) ? "AM" : "PM"; // Return AM or PM depedning of 24 Hour time
    time = hour + time.substr(2, 3) + " " + ampm;


    return time; // RETURNS 12 HOUR TIME
  }
```

https://snack.expo.io/@ammarahmed/getetatime

Comment: many thanks man, is there a way to make it a 12hr format (I mean converting to AM and PM) and also removing the seconds

Comment: I have made the edits to give time without seconds. The time is already in 12 hour format so before noon it will show AM and after noon it will show PM.

Comment: cheers once again, I noticed on expo web it does convert it to 12hrs format, but on mobile it does not 
is there a way around that?

Comment: I have made the edits. It should now work properly on mobile phone. Check the updated expo snack.

Comment: you are a life saver